# Angular using foreach loop to push objects into an array

Tags: json, angularjs, foreach

I have a complex array which has objects inside of parent objects. I've already extracted the objects I want to work with through ng-repeat and am returning them. I'd like to be able to put all of these objects into an array using an angular forEach. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Here are the objects I'm returning:

```
{"day":"21","title":"ok","summary":"ok","description":"ok","_id":"53ee9f0fc6aed109c6d33cfd"}
{"day":"2","title":"ok","summary":"ok","description":"ok","_id":"53ee9f038782309c6d892"}
{"day":"27","title":"ok","summary":"ok","description":"ok","_id":"533240fc6ae32433chd"}
```

Here is my view: The objects above are represented by 'items' in the ng-repeat.

```
    <div class="calDynamic" data-ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
<div ng-repeat="cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month">
  <div ng-if="cal != '' ">
    <div class="calendar">

    <p>{{cal}}</p>
<div ng-repeat="items in cal ">

        <a href="/events/{{items.day}}">
          <article class="eventslist">
           <div class="numberedDate">
               <h3>{{items.day}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="calInfo">
            <h5>{{items.title}}</h5>
               <p>{{items.summary}}&nbsp;<a>more</a></p>
            </div>
           </article>


      </div><!-- ng-repeat val,key -->
</div><!-- calendar -->
</div><!-- ng-if cal -->
</div><!-- ng-repeat cal -->
</div><!-- calDynamic -->
```

How would I go about using a foreach loop like the one below to store those returned objects into an array so that I could use the filter method on it?

```
var arr = [];
angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
    arr.push(item);
});
```

Comment: No, I'd like to sort the array by the 'day' value. If possible I'd like to create the array from the objects and then use that data in the view. The overall goal is to be able to use a filter on the data.

Comment: In that case just filter on the `ng-repeat="items in cal | insertdayfilterhere"`

Comment: You can also have more than one filter on a filter just use `|` to separate them if you wanted to add to the parent `ng-repeat`  `"cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month | insertdayfilterhere">`

Comment: I've tried those, it seems like the complexity of the object is preventing the filtering of the day value. Here's the entire object which the 'items' object is being pulled from.

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5"),
    "year" : {
        "December" : [],
        "November" : [],
        "October" : [],
        "September" : [],
        "August" : [],
        "July" : [ 
            {
                "day" : "21",
                "title" : "u",
                "summary" : "u",
                "description" : "ok",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5366d")
            }
        ],
        "June" : [],
        "May" : [],
        "April" : [],
        "March" : [],
        "February" : [],
        "January" : []
    },
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using angular foreach loop to rearrange JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390532/using-angular-foreach-loop-to-rearrange-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list already available in the controller you can just do a deep copy.

```
    var arr = [];
    angular.copy(items,arr);
```

*If you do not use `angular.copy()` and just try to use `arr = items;` angular will just create a pointer, which you do not want in this case*

---

[**angular.copy reference**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: I see, so 'items' in the controller will reference the variable items which is set in the view?